# jquery 1.4.2 ajax does not work with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, ajax

Greetings,

I switch to jquery 1.4 but I got this error on ajax call:

Message: This method cannot be called until the send method has been called.

Edit:  $('#AlertBar').load('/Desktop/Alerts');

Answer (score 0):

After about 9 days of study and search, I have found the solution.

Paste the following code on your xhtml page and try:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {xhr:function(){
        //return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        try{
            if(window.ActiveXObject)
                return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e){}
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }  
     });
```

Well, as I am using JSF, it worked nicely!!

Good luck.